# Junit - Asserting two identical arraylists makes test fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I´m making a test for one endpoint. This endpoint returns a list of objects, so my test consist of comparing to arraylists. The test is failing in the first element already, even when the log shows that the object´s fields are identical:

*org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: iterable contents differ at index [0], expected: <Dispatch(dispatchNumber=1, creationDate=null, pickUpDate=null, completionDate=null, estimatedDate=null, deliverymanName=edgar, receiverName=null, receiverTlfNumber=null, status=null)> but was: <{dispatchNumber=1, creationDate=null, pickUpDate=null, completionDate=null, estimatedDate=null, deliverymanName=edgar, receiverName=null, receiverTlfNumber=null, status=null}>*

Here's the test's code:

```
@Test
void whenFindByUser(){
    Dispatch disp1 = new Dispatch();
    disp1.setDispatchNumber(1);
    disp1.setDeliverymanName("edgar");

    Dispatch disp2 = new Dispatch();
    disp2.setDispatchNumber(2);
    disp2.setDeliverymanName("paola");

    Dispatch disp3 = new Dispatch();
    disp3.setDispatchNumber(3);
    disp3.setDeliverymanName("marco");

    List<Dispatch> dummyDispatches = new ArrayList<Dispatch>(Arrays.asList(disp1, disp2, disp3));

    when(service.findByUser("123")).thenReturn(dummyDispatches);

    List<Dispatch> realDispatches = restClient.getForObject(localhost + port + "/find/user/123", dummyDispatches.getClass());

    //assertArrayEquals(dummyDispatches.toArray(), realDispatches.toArray());
    //assertEquals(dummyDispatches.get(1), realDispatches.get(1));
    assertIterableEquals(dummyDispatches, realDispatches);
}
```

The commented functions at the end of the test are other approaches that I took to make it work, but it was useless.

Comment: Your log shows nothing of the kind. Examine it _in detail_, and specifically the type of the objects inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message again. Compare the two values:

```java
<Dispatch(dispatchNumber=1, creationDate=null, pickUpDate=null, completionDate=null, estimatedDate=null, deliverymanName=edgar, receiverName=null, receiverTlfNumber=null, status=null)>

<{dispatchNumber=1, creationDate=null, pickUpDate=null, completionDate=null, estimatedDate=null, deliverymanName=edgar, receiverName=null, receiverTlfNumber=null, status=null}>
```

If they had been equal, the 2 values would look exactly the same, but they don't.
The first has `Dispatch(...)`, the second has `{...}`.

Why is that? Well, the first is the result of calling `toString()` on the `Dispatch` class. The second is not, it cannot be, so what is it?

If we look back at where the second comes from, we find:

```java
List<Dispatch> realDispatches = restClient.getForObject(..., dummyDispatches.getClass());
```

The problem is that, because of *type erasure*, `dummyDispatches.getClass()` is the same as `List.class`, i.e. the method is only told to parse into a `List`, but not what kind of object should go in the list.

Without knowing the kind of object, it parses into a `Map<String, Object>`, which fits the output of the second value, i.e. `{name=value, ...}`.

But, you then say, the return value is declared as `List<Dispatch>`, not `List<Map<String, Object>>`, so why don't we get an error?

Because `List.class` is a *raw* type, making return value declared as a *raw* `List<Map>`, and being *raw* it silently is considered assignment-compatible with `List<Map<ANYTHING>>`, for backwards-compatibility reasons.

In IDEs, you can enable compiler warnings to alert you to this kind of issue.

*Solution:* Change to use array, since array component type is retained at runtime:

```java
Dispatch[] realDispatches = restClient.getForObject(..., Dispatch[].class);
```

That will of course affect your `assert` call, but you can convert to list using `Arrays.asList(...)`.